Python: шифрование данных в коде
Пишу программу. Одна из задач - подключение к БД.
HOST = 'localhost' # Хост
USERNAME = 'admin' # Логин
PASSWORD = '' # Пароль (надо спрятать)
DATABASE = 'db01' # Бд (надо спрятать)

Предположим, что нарушитель решил проверить, что находится в программе  и вскрыл её. Как защитить несколько строк, чтоб вместо ожидаемого читаемого пароля и БД нарушитель получил лишь набор непонятных символов? Хочу заметить, что использование hash не решает мою проблему из-за причин, которые, к сожалению, сообщить не могу.

не хранить пароли в коде, использовать переменные среды (для начала) для чувствительных данных и использовать любую из предоставленных возможностей читать эти данные.

Ваша программа не должна знать ничего о БД и ее подключении. Она должна отправлять данные на "серверную" часть, закрытую от посторонних глаз, где и должно быть организовано общение с БД. Сам клиент должен только слать запросы к серверу на ту или иную операцию. Передать программу с прямым доступом к БД пользователю - лучше сами убейте БД любым досутпным вам способом...

вы знаки препинания принципиально не используете?

Само по себе шифрование текстовых строк - задача, которая входит даже в школьную программу. Но это ж резкое усложнение процесса. Я присоединяюсь к мнениям выше - пересмотрите идеологию.

«Хочу заметить, что использование hash не решает мою проблему из-за причин, которые, к сожалению, сообщить не могу.»  - Очень интересно...
